# OnClickListener for MaterialCardView inside Compound View in Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I created a compound view that consists of two MaterialCardViews. I was curious if there is any way I can access the onClickListener on each of them separately from another file (for example the main activity). This is because I would like to trigger different events for each of them.

As of now, I have created the compound layout within a `<merge>` tag in an XML file and created a `CompoundViewName` class file in Kotlin.

I'm able to access onClickListener for each MaterialCardView (using findViewById) within the class file, but I would like to access them from another file, for instance, the MainActivity.kt file where the CompoundView is being rendered.

It would be great if you could guide me in the right direction. Kindly, let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: It sounds like you just new to add a few methods to `CompoundViewName` to set the listeners where they're needed; e.g., `fun setButtonOneOnClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener) { buttonOne.setOnClickListener(listener) }`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.